# UMDH Logs (Memory Leak on Windows)

Tags: windows, memory-leaks

I am using UMDH tool to analyze the memory leaks of my application.

The top leaks observed by UMDH logs are as follows:

- 237856226 ( 241016812 - 3160586) 3704833 allocs    BackTraceE9
- 3685198 ( 3704833 -  19635)          BackTraceE9   allocations
          ntdll!RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW+00011866
          ntdll!RtlSubAuthorityCountSid+00000019
          MSVCR80!malloc+0000007A
- 207093760 ( 207355904 - 262144)    791 allocs     BackTrace6EB
- 790 (    791 -      1)           BackTrace6EB allocations
          ntdll!RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW+00011866
          ntdll!RtlSubAuthorityCountSid+00000019
          php5ts!zend_register_internal_class_ex+000001A5

I have built my application in debug mode and specified the PDB files in the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH. 
But I am still unable to see the stack trace from my application. For example in the above log "MSVCR80!malloc+0000007A" malloc is being called , but no idea from which part of my application.

What extra configuration is required so that debug symbols will be visible in the UMDH logs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a terrible oversight on Microsoft's part.  [Here are the details](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=209).  You are basically out of luck with this version of Microsoft's CRT library.